# IDataReader Issue in .Net 1.1 and .Net 4.0 for Sybase DB

Tags: .net-4.0, sybase, .net-1.1, oledbconnection, idatareader

I have a sybase DB which fetches results of a query properly as below...

```
select   
    S.ipoInternalID,  
    clientAccount,  
    clientPrice,  
    clientAccountType,  
    interestOnLoan = 
               CASE WHEN useHIBOR = 1 then  
                    ROUND(financingAmount * (fixedRate + spreadRate) * 
                            I.noOfDaysForInterest/365/100,2)
               ELSE 
                    ROUND(financingAmount * (I.fundingRate+ spreadRate) * 
                           I.noOfDaysForInterest/365/100,2) END,
    useHIBORSTR = 
               CASE WHEN useHIBOR = 1 then
                    "LOCK-IN RATE + SPREAD" 
               ELSE
                    "COST OF FUNDING + SPREAD" END,
from subscription S, iPO I, allocation A  
where   
            S.ipoInternalID = @ipoInternalID  and  
            I.ipoInternalID = @ipoInternalID  and  
            A.ipoInternalID = @ipoInternalID  and
            S.ccassID *= A.ccassID  
order by  S.ccassID
```

Notice the way `interestOnLoan` field is calculated above.

Now when I run this query in SQL Advantage tool, it runs fine and gives me calculated values for `interestOnLoan`. When I run this query using .Net 1.1 API that loads this query via OleDB it runs fine...

```
myCommand.CommandText = myQuery;
myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
int i = myAdapter.Fill(resultSet);
```

My resultset fills ok.

But when I execute the above code in .net 4.0, the resultset errors out as

> **"Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal."**

The value it has issues with is the `interestOnLoan` because I also executed the command via `IDataReader` as below...

```
  using (var dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
  {
         resultSet.Tables.Add(ConvertDataReaderToTableManually(dr));
  }

private static DataTable ConvertDataReaderToTableManually(IDataReader dr) {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var dtSchema = dr.GetSchemaTable();
    var listCols = new List<DataColumn>();

    if (dtSchema != null) {
        foreach (DataRow drow in dtSchema.Rows) {
        var columnName = Convert.ToString(drow["ColumnName"]);
        var t = (Type) (drow["DataType"]);
        var column = new DataColumn(columnName, t);
        column.Unique = (bool) drow["IsUnique"];
        column.AllowDBNull = (bool) drow["AllowDBNull"];
        column.AutoIncrement = (bool) drow["IsAutoIncrement"];
        listCols.Add(column);
        dt.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }

    // Read rows from DataReader and populate the DataTable
    int j = 0;

    while (dr.Read()) {
        j++;
        var dataRow = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < listCols.Count; i++) {
        try {
            dataRow[((DataColumn)listCols[i])] = dr[i];
        } catch (Exception ex1) { }         
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return dt;
    }
```

Here it errors out at the `dataRow[((DataColumn)listCols[i])] = dr[i]` where it has issues **reading from dr[i]**;

When observed the `i`th column is nothing but **interestOnLoan**.

So somehow .Net 4.0 is not able to read this value. It can read other decimal values correctly such as `clientPrice`.

Why could this be happening....

Also I wanted to ask is there any way I can load the values in the `DataReader` as `Double` (instead of `Decimal`) by default?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get the reason why .NET 4.0 had issues ith the above query but when I changed the query as below it worked in both (.Net 1.1 and 4.0)

```
select   
  S.ipoInternalID,  
  clientAccount,  
  clientPrice,  
  clientAccountType,  
  interestOnLoan = ROUND(
     (CASE WHEN useHIBOR = 1 THEN
           ((financingAmount*(fixedRate + spreadRate) * .noOfDaysForInterest)/365.0)
           ELSE 
           ((financingAmount*(I.fundingRate+spreadRate)*I.noOfDaysForInterest)/365.0)
     END) / 100.0, 2),
  useHIBORSTR = 
                   CASE WHEN useHIBOR = 1 then
                   "LOCK-IN RATE + SPREAD" 
                   ELSE
                  "COST OF FUNDING + SPREAD" END,
 from subscription S, iPO I , allocation A  
 where   
                S.ipoInternalID = @ipoInternalID  and  
                I.ipoInternalID = @ipoInternalID  and  
                A.ipoInternalID = @ipoInternalID  and
                S.ccassID *= A.ccassID  
 order by  S.ccassID
```